# Doctrine не подтягивать все связи

Tags: php, symfony3, doctrine

Например, когда я пишу так: `$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ProfileBundle:User')->findBy(['deletedAt' => null]);`
то к модели пользователя подтягиваются все связанные таблицы. Что если они мне не нужны на данный момент? Это лишняя нагрузка на базу и лишняя информация, которая не будет использоваться. Как сделать так, что бы вытягивались только те связи что мне нужны?

Я использую jms_serializer, это он при вызове метода  `$users = $this->container->get('jms_serializer')->toArray($users);` вытягивает все связи.

Я хочу чтоб было так - у меня есть связь к таблице currensies, но я не хочу что бы она показывалась как вложенный объект, а хочу чтоб показывалась как поле currensy_id, так как оно и сеть в базе, а из остальных связанных таблиц показывать только определенные

Comment: ну так вытягиваются связи, а не данные по этим связям )

Comment: @madfan41k данные вытягиваются в процессе сериализации

Comment: @Jonny Manowar попробуйте использовать встроенный сериализатор, с картой того, что вы хотите выводить. в этом случае связи будут продолжать доставаться, но не вытягиваться из бд

Comment: @StereoFlo а с этим я и не спорил )))